# Copy from sheet 1 to sheet 2 every 50th row

Tags: excel

I need to copy data from tab1(sheet 1) to tab2(sheet2) every 50 lines. I can get it to do it manually, but when I try and copy the formula down after setting up a few cells it gives me random cells not every 50 like what was in the previous formulas.

Comment: what formula are you using?

Comment: ='Sheet 1'!A2    ='Sheet 1'!A52      ='Sheet 1'!A102

Comment: do you want sheet1!a52 in cell sheet2!a3 or sheet2!a52?

Comment: I would like "='Sheet 1'!A2" in the a1 cell in sheet 2. Then "='Sheet 1'!A52" in the a2 cell in sheet 2. Then "='Sheet 1'!a102" in the a3 cell in sheet 2. And I would like that to repeat as many times as I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Index` and `Row` to achieve this..

for example the following formula in column B

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW()-1)*50+2,0)
```

will return back

```
B1 = A2
B2 = A52
B3 = A102
```

....

Comment: Sam, I've edited your formula to `=INDEX(A:A,(ROW()-1)*50+2,0)` as OP wants cell A2 returned before A52.

Comment: I rolled back. If you want to propose an edit to a formula do it in the comment section. This changes the original intent of the author.

Answer (score 1):

If you place this formula in row 1 of any column it will return the proper pattern (2, 52, 102...)

```
=INDIRECT("A" & 2 + 50*(ROW()-1))
```

However note that INDIRECT is a volatile formula. This will slow your workbook if you have a lot of calculations and a lot of calls to INDIRECT().

Comment: +1 works, but there are less indirect ways of getting it with index or offset.

Comment: How is it less indirect with index and offset ? They also have to specify the column and use `ROW()`.

Answer (score 1):

in sheet2!A1, use the following formula, then copy down:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1+(ROW()-1)*50,0,,)
```

Comment: +1.. Offset was my alternate choice but I think that Index performs slightly better.